# place one object on left and second on right

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

My screen looks like this:

[image]

Currently, the text comes at the top while the red section (VideoComponent) comes at the bottom. I want the VideoComponent to appear on the left side while all the text should move towards the right. Like a flexbox maybe?

```
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="content">
                In this section.....TEXT
<div className="video">
                    <VideoComponent />
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
```

The VideoComponent:

```
    return (
    <div>
        <Sketch className="sketch" />
        </div>
    </div>)
```

css for video

```
.sketch{
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.button{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.secondbutton{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to wrap around the video, use float. In the example below, I have a paragraph of text that I want to wrap around two images, so I insert the images in the p tag where I want them to be vertically, and use float: left.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
   <img id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   <img id="right"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: You can see in the code snippet that I shared that it absolutely works. If it is not rendering properly in your code base, the most likely cause is that you have written other CSS that is overwriting this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that flex is better than float.

```
return (
    <div>
        <main className="content">
            <div className="video">
                <VideoComponent />
            </div>
            <div className="text">
                In this section.....TEXT
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
);

CSS
.context {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```